# Instead of tabs, is it possible to save links and read them one by one?

Tags: browser

My reading style is as follows:

1. Open the main page of, say, a newspaper.
2. Review the entire main page and open the links I want to read in a new tab. This usually results in 30-40 tabs
3. Read and close tabs one by one.

Unfortunately, Chrome for Android crashes frequently if many tabs are open. So I'm looking for a way (addon, app) to a different workflow:

1. same
2. Review the entire main page and add the links I want to read to a reading list.
3. Walk through the reading list: read the first article, touch Next, etc.

Comment: What device and Android version are you using? I never have any problems with Chrome on SGNII 4.1.2 2GB RAM.

Comment: Galaxy Tab 2, Android 4.2.2. The crash would not be a serious problem if it could recover from it. But it forgets the tabs that were open last time.

Comment: Oh, so you have 1GB RAM I guess. It could be the culprit of your problems with Chrome on Touchwiz device.

Answer (score 2):

Try Link Bubble: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.linkbubble.playstore

If I decide I'm done reading, I share the links I've opened to Pocket so I can read them later.

Pocket: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ideashower.readitlater.pro

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work well with Chrome. Links clicked in Chrome open in Chrome.

Comment: @Arthur I think you have to "share" the links to have Link Bubble listed.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a Google account I recommend you **Google Keep** (http://drive.google.com/keep). It's fast and does not require to download anything (just the app on mobile devices), it's all in the cloud.

You can save the links in a note and open them later. All your notes are synched across your devices. You can also share content to and from keep to store your links and stuff.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't really want to save the links, just open a lot of them as fast as possible and then quickly walk on the opened pages. Something like going through a folder of images in an image viewer.

Comment: Something like a web browser that doesn't load the url until you navigate to it, while saving a snapshot of the page so you can know the content of that url while sliding through them? I don't know anything similar but I think it has potential for a good project.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you don't need to get away from tabs, you just need your browser to not crash. I just did a quick stress test of [Firefox for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.firefox), and got to 72 tabs before encountering any issues on my Nexus 4. It might be that it can better handle your workflow than Chrome can.

Comment: Thanks, that could be an option if there was an addon that would make it easy to move to the next tab, for example with a  gesture. Switching tabs via the sidebar is a bit clumsy in Firefox.

Comment: FWIW I'm currently sitting on ~100 tabs in Chrome on Nexus 5. The tab count changes to an emoticon when you get above 99. No crashes.